# current_page? in a _partial view keeps erroring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm using a _form partial which contains my Create and Edit template for my model Products.

I have the following code to check if it's the Edit View

`<% current_page?(edit_product_path(@product)) %>`

However when I enter the create view the site falls over with the following error

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: your variable `@product` is `nil` in your case

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a controller

Comment: @MrYoshiji I understand that the id is missing How would i check if it's the edit path from another view? It seems kind of irrelevant to check like this if it only works inside certain scenarios.

Comment: the answer is in your response : "it only works inside certain scenarios", then use a logical `if` statement defining these "scenarios" (something like @ArslanAli posted or a simple `if @product.persisted? && current_page?([...])`)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thank you very much I actually used a combination for yours and Arshans answer.  It's always difficult when you start something new :)  Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edit_product_path()` expects an `id` of the product you wish to edit, but in your case, somehow `@product` is `nil`, therefore, you are getting the error. And since, there is a possibility that it may again be `nil` in the future, you have to put a check:

```
<% if @product %>
  <% current_page?(edit_product_path(@product) %>
  <%# Your other code %>
<% end %>
```